# Geb If Else or try catch handling

Tags: geb

I am new to Geb spoke testing and I have a test that ui send message and receive text or email, I have an api call that grabs the sent email/text, I need to use that response and continue in the UI testing. but that response is expired since the api is fast and its getting the previous  sent message which (before my ui send that email/text) and the last sent makes the previous expired. so my question is I need to call that api again if the message is expired, I tried if else and waitFor methods but couldn't come up with solution, I use page objects and test specs and I cannot create that as a method since that is happening on one page and in one def class and which I cannot even do waitFor in my test class which results IllegalMonitorStateException

```groovy
when: "I enter text code"
String text = response.getText()
testPage.enterCode << text
testpage.pager.clickNext() // here is happening the code expiration and couldn't get to the next page,

then: "I am in next page"
at nextPage // if am not on the next page I need to make a new api call to get the newest response
```

I tried

```groovy
when: "I enter text code"
String text = response.getText()
testPage.enterCode << text
testpage.pager.clickNext() 
def erroHappened = testPage.errorAlert.isdisplayed

then: "I am in next page"
!errorHappened && testPage.enterCode << response.getText()
```

How can I use the wait or try catch or if else to solve this issue, Thank you in advance

Comment: Welcome to SO. I tried to carefully read and understand your question, but I failed. Sorry, it is unclear to me what problem you are trying to solve. I believe it would be helpful to let code speak and make your problem reproducible for everyone. So please share an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Your small code snippets do not explain enough about what you want to do and what the actual problem is. Maybe a colleague with better command of English can help you edit the question and explain more clearly. No offence meant.